# Tabulator table width problem using css grid

Tags: css, css-grid, tabulator

I've got a [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) table inside a page that uses css grid for layout. When I resize the browser, I want the table to grow and shrink with the view. This works fine when outside of css grid, but fails when inside my css grid.  When using css grid, the Tabulator table expands correctly when the browser is resized wider, but never shrinks when the browser view gets narrower. Instead, scrollbars appear and the table remains wide.

```js
var data = [
    { name: '1', description: 'Description of thing 1', location: 'Location 1' },
    { name: '2', description: 'Description of thing 2', location: 'Location 2' },
    { name: '3', description: 'Description of thing 3', location: 'Location 3' },
];
var cols = [
    { field: 'name', title: 'Name', width: '20%', widthGrow: 1, widthShrink: 1  },
    { field: 'description', title: 'Description', width: '30%', widthGrow: 1, widthShrink: 1    },
    { field: 'location', title: 'Location', width: '50%', widthGrow: 1, widthShrink: 1   },
];

var config = {
    columns: cols,
    data: data,
    layout: 'fitColumns'
};
var mytable = new Tabulator("#mytable", config);
```

```css
.main-body {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    height: 100vh;
}


/* If I use the below css instead, the table shrinking works correctly. */
/*
.main-body {
    width: 100%;
}
*/
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.4.3/css/tabulator.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/4.4.3/js/tabulator.js"></script>


When the view is made wider, the table expands correctly.
When it's made narrower, the table does not shrink correctly.
In the snippet view, it's easiest to use "full page" mode to see the issue.

<div class="main-body">
  <div class="main-content">
    <div id="mytable"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I instead change the `main-body` css to remove the grid, the table resizes correctly.

```
.main-body {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The grid here is contrived for the purpose of creating a simplified example. My actual grid is more complicated, so I'd prefer to keep using the grid here.

How can I get my tabulator table to both expand and contract with the browser width here?

[image]

Here's a fiddle which uses css grid and shows the table resize problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/cfarmerga/wtqo65uc/26/

Here's a fiddle which does not use css grid, and shows the table resizing correctly:
https://jsfiddle.net/cfarmerga/wtqo65uc/29/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Fair point.  I added this, but the issue is somewhat easier to see in the fiddle, since that view makes it easier to resize just the result view portion.

Answer (score 5):

Not unexpectedly, this is an issue with my use of CSS grid rather than tabulator itself. This post on CSS grid blowout was helpful: https://css-tricks.com/preventing-a-grid-blowout/

Changing my css to provide an explicit minimum size for the grid was all it took.

```
.main-body {
    ...
    grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr);
    ...
}
```